# macro vb script for pop up box in Excell

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have 3 columns `A,B,C` where `C` is the ID and the rest 2 have values. If I change some values in `A` or `B` columns, I need to get a pop up message box which shows the ID of the row which was changed (EX: If I change row 10 column A value, then in the pop up it should show the ID of row 10 in column `C`).

Please help me on this.
Below is the script that I have tried, but I am not able to populate the column `C` value,I can only able to populate the next column value for which the value has changed (Ex: If I change the value of column `A` pop is showing the value of Column `B`, but I need the value of column `C`)

Please find the script I am using

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not (Application.Intersect(Range("A1:C16"), Target) Is Nothing) Then
        MsgBox Target.Next & "" & Target.Address & " has changed.", vbInformation
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try code below. It will give you address of changed cell and ID value of row in which change occurred.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not (Application.Intersect(Range("A1:C16"), Target) Is Nothing) Then
        MsgBox "ID:" & Cells(Target.Row, 3) & "-" & Replace(Target.Address, "$", "") & " has changed.", vbInformation
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of Target.Address if I use Target.Column I am getting the column number , Can I get the column name like "A", because if I use address it is showing $ symbol

Comment: hi, please find adjusted code to remove $ sign from address.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick response:)

Comment: Instead of range "Range("A1:C16")" like this can I use column names.
For ex column names are like "Name", "Age", etc

Comment: You can use named ranges. check here for more info ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46407862/macro-vb-script-for-pop-up-box-in-excell/46408065?noredirect=1#comment79812645_46408065

Comment: I think you have my link only:)